# upgrading a weblogic config.xml version 8.1.6.0 to10.3.5

Tags: weblogic, upgrade, config

I have been given a weblogic assignment for my internship, but i have never worked with weblogic before. I have been told that the config.xml needs to be updated. are there any samples or suggestions as to how to go about updating an 8.1 config to a 10.3?
i have been reading through a few oracle pages, but i am still confused. can a config.xml be upgraded using workshop? 
thank you for your time.

Comment: have a look at this [upgrade guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wlw/docs103/guide/upgrading/ovwGuidelinesForUpgrade.html)